# Copy-Item PowerShell silently continues when source is a network share that does not exist

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm seeing a strange behavior with the "Copy-Item" cmdlet. It looks like the cmdlet errors out if the source location is a local location that does not exist, but completely ignores that if the source is a network location that does not exist.

For e.g.

```
Copy-Item \\server\share\thisdoesnotexist\* -Destination c:\temp -ErrorAction Stop
```

This command doesn't show any errors even if the source share is invalid. However,

```
Copy-Item c:\thisdoesnotexist\* -Destination c:\temp -ErrorAction Stop
```

throws an error that looks like:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\thisdoesnotexist' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item c:\thisdoesnotexist\* -Destination c:\temp -ErrorAction Stop;
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\thisdoesnotexist:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

What's going on here? I checked [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849793.aspx) but couldn't see anything there that talked about this. My question is:

- Is this expected?
- Is there a way to make the cmdlet fail when source network share is invalid as well?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: I can confirm these finding with PowerShell 3.0. Might be a bug but it would be good measure to test these paths before hand with `Test-Path` anyway. This might be because of the 2 different providers

Comment: Both are using the FileSystem provider, right?

Comment: Also happens on Powershell 4.0. When you remove the asterisk it will give you the correct error. In any case, you should always test your paths before you do a `Copy-Item` (see [Test-Path](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx))

Comment: Thanks folks. I'll go with Test-Path before the copy to make sure they exist. I also posted this on https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1234831/copy-item-powershell-silently-continues-when-source-is-a-network-share-that-does-not-exist.

If any of you can vote on it, maybe it'll help get traction on their end.